# Linear transformation that sends $ax+by+cz=0$ to $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I was thinking, can we always find a projective transformation to send any projective line to the line at infinity? After a while I figured that this can certainly be achieved because the projective line is just the projection of a plane passing through the origin. Therefore we can achieve that by letting the projective transformation  be induced by a linear transformation rotating our plane by a suitable rotation so that the projection of that plane is the line at infinity.

Having that in mind we conclude that the question of writing down the projective transformation boils down to answering the following question:

> Let $P$ be defined as the set of $(x,y,z)$ such that $ax+by+cz=0$. How can we find a linear transormation to send $P$ to $x=0$?

Comment: You need to send the normal of your plane to a certain normal.

Comment: Without additional constraints $f(x,y,z)=0$ is also a valid solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is that is necessary or sufficient? The transformation needn't preserve orthogonality.

Comment: To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Comment: I added information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Take a basis $(v_1,v_2)$ for the plane $P$ and complete it on a basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ for $\Bbb R^3$. Now we see that $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis for the plane $x=0$ where $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$ and complete it on basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. Finally a linear transformation $T$ is entirely determined by giving its action on a basis so for example let

$$T(v_1)=e_2\quad;\quad T(v_2)=e_3\quad;\quad T(v_3)=e_1$$
so $T$ sends $P$ to $x=0$.

Comment: Cheers!, nice answer

Comment: You're welcome.